# Pythonic way to control an attribute over another attribute

Tags: python, class, attributes, controls

There is a pythonic way to control attributes?
I wan't that the init method is clear, trying to avoid to use a function like:

```py
self.a = check_a_greater_than_b(a)
```

and avoid to do controls in the init method

```py
def __init__(self, a, b):
    if b > a:
        raise AttributeError('A should be > B')
    else:
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

I was think to use the setter or settattr, can you post me an example please?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```
class Object():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.b = b
        self.a = a

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self.__a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, a):
        assert a > self.b, "A should be > B"
        self.__a = a
```

Then you will have :

```
o = Object(3,2)
o.a = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 12, in a
AssertionError: A should be > B
```

Comment: Yes, that is fine. I was thinking that something that workig on multiple attributes, but problably in that case it would be better to use a decorator on the init method.
On a single attribute your way is preferable. Thanks

Comment: Just one detail: `assert` should not be used to validate data. Raise a `ValueError` instead. https://realpython.com/python-assert-statement/#when-not-to-use-assertions

Comment: Yes, I think LCMa is using assert for a brief example. I use the asserts 90% of time in unit testing :D
@VPfB Why using ValueError instead of AttributeError?

Comment: @EdoardoZucchelli I think that error perfectly describes the situation - a value is not in the expected range. See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError